# Ubuntu Wubi Kernel Panic

Tags: ubuntu, boot, multi-boot, wubi, kernel-panic

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 through Wubi to a Windows 7 NTFS drive. Everything worked ok -- after I booted into Ubuntu I did all the upgrades and everything was ok and I rebooted etc. However today, after the first cold boot Ubuntu does a kernel panic and I see a purple screen.

Since Wubi uses the Windows Boot Manager I can't set nomodeset or remove quite splash, so I have no way to see whats going on or causing the panic, I just get a purple screen and a flashing caps lock.

Does anyone know what happened and how to fix it?

Comment: I think wubu uses grub4dos as its bootloader, so if you press ESC very fast after you selected the entry from Windows bootmgr, you might get the grub menu. You can use 'e' or 'c' from there.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use Wubi on XP. I had to replace my H/W and it came with Win. 7. Because the boot process is different on Win. 7 than XP, I installed VirtualBox on Win. 7 and then installed a couple of Ubuntu distros using VirtualBox. I find the performance to be quite fast. My new H/W is an AMD64, but I installed the 32bit versions of Ubuntu and Mint in VirtualBox. One drawback is access to the Win. 7 directories where I store my data. I haven't investigated how to share a directory between Win. 7 and my distros in VB. Currently, I use either an external HD, USB stick or Dropbox. If you get the Wubi problem resolved, you can still try VirtualBox or VM Player from VMWare - both are free.